# Can someone tell me why this isn't a good way to assign $_POST vars?

Tags: php

I am wondering if anyone can suggest a more elegant way to assign variables during PHP/mySQL form submission.  This seems clunky

```
    //include("connect.php");
        mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
        mysql_select_db("noirTEST");
        // assign out vars from the POST vars to get ready for SQL insertion
        $thumb_image_location = $_POST['thumb_image_location'];
        $large_image_location = $_POST['large_image_location'];
        $password = sanitizeString($_POST['password1']);
        $firstName = sanitizeString($_POST['firstName']);
        $lastName = sanitizeString($_POST['lastName']);
        $desc_short = sanitizeString($_POST['desc_short']);
        $nationality = sanitizeString($_POST['nationality']);
        $speakEnglish = sanitizeString($_POST['speakEnglish']);
        $speakGerman = sanitizeString($_POST['speakGerman']);
        $mainInst = sanitizeString($_POST['mainInst']);
        $inspiration1 = sanitizeString($_POST['inspiration1']);
        $inspiration2 = sanitizeString($_POST['inspiration2']);
        $inspiration3 = sanitizeString($_POST['inspiration3']);
        $inspiration4 = sanitizeString($_POST['inspiration4']);
        $inspiration5 = sanitizeString($_POST['inspiration5']);
        $desc_long = sanitizeString($_POST['desc_long']);
        $link1name = sanitizeString($_POST['link1name']);
        $link1url = sanitizeString($_POST['link1url']);
        $link2name = sanitizeString($_POST['link2name']);
        $link2url = sanitizeString($_POST['link2url']);
        $link3name = sanitizeString($_POST['link3name']);
        $link3url = sanitizeString($_POST['link3url']);
        $email = sanitizeString($_POST['email']);
        $proExperience = sanitizeString($_POST['proExperience']);
        $haveStudio = sanitizeString($_POST['haveStudio']);
        $musicTheory = sanitizeString($_POST['musicTheory']);
        $composer = sanitizeString($_POST['composer']);
        $teacher = sanitizeString($_POST['teacher']);

        $query = "INSERT INTO NOIRusers (thumb_image_location, large_image_location, password, firstName, lastName, desc_short, nationality, speakEnglish, speakGerman, mainInst, inspiration1, inspiration2, inspiration3, inspiration4, inspiration5, desc_long, link1name, link1url, link2name, link2url, link3name, link3url, email, proExperience, haveStudio, musicTheory, composer, teacher ) VALUES ('$thumb_image_location', '$large_image_location', '$password', '$firstName', '$lastName', '$desc_short', '$nationality', '$speakEnglish', '$speakGerman','$mainInst',  '$inspiration1', '$inspiration2', '$inspiration3', '$inspiration4', '$inspiration5', '$desc_long', '$link1name', '$link1url', '$link2name', '$link2url', '$link3name', '$link3url', '$email', '$proExperience', '$haveStudio', '$musicTheory', '$composer', '$teacher')";

    function sanitizeString($string)
        {
            $string=trim($string);
            $string=strip_tags($string);
            $string=htmlentities($string);
            $string=stripslashes($string);
            return $string;
        };
```

Would something like this work for the long first part?

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    ${$key} = $value;
    sanitizeString($key);
}
```

It seems like every example I am seeing uses the long way or something like it .. so I am sure there is a reason why a shorter way can't / shouldn't be used.  But can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: The short way is fine if you want a variable for each array value, named as per the key. What does sanitizeString() do, as you use it on the password?

Comment: I would do the foreach that you list below, but also instead of saving in individual variables, create an array of variables where the key is the same as the $_POST key used.

Comment: @cez - Oops.  I guess it doesnt make sense to use sanitizeString on the password.  As for having variables named per the key - that seems to be logical to me although I can imagine this is not always desired.

Comment: @cilosis - I'm not sure what you mean.  What would be the point of putting this in an array if it is just immediately going to be INSERTED as in the example?  What is the advantage of an array in this case?

Answer (score 2):

For one you should use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) as well, inside your `sanitizeString` function.

Or better yet, use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php), which will escape your strings for you.

Comment: You mean [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)?

Comment: One point for the tips, and yes.. I realize PDO is a better way to do this, but since this is my first trial at this, I figured I would do one test in mysql, one with mysqli, and then one with PDO so I could get a feel for the diffs.  

And "whoops" with the escape_string. I knew that.  Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Your alternative does just do the same as enabling register_globals, which is a very bad idea (if you *really* wanted to do that, you could just use [extract](http://www.php.net/extract) together with [array_map](http://www.php.net/array_map) - but don't.).

I'd suggest either looping through and sanitizing the values in $_POST (preferable in a new array, so that you have control over which values have been filtered and which has not), or by simply using the value filtered in your query (you probably want to take a look at using prepared queries as well). You could also create a list of the expected, set form values, and then loop through that list and check and filter the values as you come across them. This will allow you to check that the value actually is set and that the request contains what you'd expected.

You also want to avoid using stripslashes() unless magic_quotes have been enabled, otherwise you'll lose valid -s in your sanitize function, using strip_tags will remove a bit too much content if your field contain a <, and you want to do HTML escaping output (to HTML), not input.

Comment: Good info.  Someone above recommended putting the results into an array as well.  SO I guess you would initialize an array() and then use array_push inside the loop? 

Would that do as you said?  As for creating a list of expected form values, I've seen that.  But  if you use jQuery at the front (making sure required fields are there etc), then all you want to make sure at this stage is that malicious code isn't getting in, or?  What would I want to be validating with your advice, for example?